# How to clear all filters in react-table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am using react-table v7 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table) . I am able to filter the data (referred from https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/filtering ) and I am using SelectColumnFilter function for all the columns to filter . I would like to create a button which will reset all the filters. Like If I have applied filters to 4 columns by clicking on the RESET ALL button I want all the filters to be cleared. Can someone please help me with this ?
Thank you

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can get the setAllFilters method from useTable instance, and then

```
const { ...setAllFilters } = useTable({ columns, data }, userFilters)

// somewhere at you code
<button onClick={() => setAllFilters([])}>Reset</button>
```

checkout setAllFilters at https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/blob/master/docs/api/useFilters.md

Comment: Hey @goldenbearkin , Thanks for the answer . It did reset the table but the filtered values (which got filtered through the SelectColumnFilter ) are not cleared . Can u help me how to clear those too ???

Comment: @blessyjulie, Can you make an example in codesandbox?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-rhodes-bl0k8?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark   If u filter the First Name from All -> to any specific value and when u select the RESET BUTTON then the table resets but the value in the Filter which we converted from All-> to any specific value remains as it is. Can u help me to clear that tooo ???

Comment: how about this? https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-shtern-ijc5o I make value={filterValue || "All"} (see line 76).